# Unable to sort Orders on customer order page by meta value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to filter WC orders on customer order dashboard page using `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` filter. and Order by date, title etc are working fine for me but when i try to filter orders by custom meta keys and values then it’s not returning me correct result.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'af_filter_orders', 10, 1 );

function af_filter_orders( $orders ) { 

    $orders = array(
     'limit'       => -1,
     'offset'      => null,
     'page'        => 1,
     'meta_key' => 'custom_meta_key', //meta type is plain string and i need results alphabetically.
     'orderby' => 'meta_value', //meta_value_num
     'order' => 'DESC', //ASC
     'customer' => get_current_user_id(),  
     'paginate' => true
    );
    return $orders;

}
```

I am on WC v2.6. have not tested on 3x yet. and i need it working with 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in WooCommerce below 3.0, `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` is an array of args used for `get_post`.

In this, I think your `$orders` array should include meta_query for it to work correctly.

```
$orders = array(
     'limit'       => -1,
     'offset'      => null,
     'page'        => 1,
     'meta_key' => 'custom_meta_key', //meta type is plain string and i need results alphabetically.
     'orderby' => 'meta_value', //meta_value_num
     'order' => 'DESC', //ASC
     'customer' => get_current_user_id(),  
     'paginate' => true,
     'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'custom_meta_key', //meta type is plain string and i need results alphabetically.
                'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
                'compare' => 'IN',
           ),
      ),
 );
```

in WooCommerce 3.0.x, `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` is used for `wc_get_orders` where your args are limited to what is given. `meta_key` and `meta_query` is not acceptable args. And so will not work. However, the query is handle at the end with a filter `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query` that you can use. It is basically calling `WP_Query`. Where `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query` is the filter for the args.

**P.S.**
I think in 3.1.x, they've removed the `wp_parse_args` of `wc_get_orders`. This means `meta_key` and `meta_query` will work when you pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'af_filter_orders', 10, 1);

function af_filter_orders($orders) {
    $orders = array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'offset' => null,
        'page' => 1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'custom_meta_key',
                'value' => $value,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ), //meta type is plain string and i need results alphabetically.
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', //meta_value_num
        'order' => 'DESC', //ASC
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'paginate' => true
    );
    return $orders;
}
```